# How can i get register adress (ex: ($s2)) in datapath?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I understood every part of datapath but i couldn't clearly understood how to get memory address of a register.  For example, in a hypothetical new instruction like `J 200($s1)`

(mips language)

[image: My Datapath:]

Comment: I don't think a register has a memory address because it is not stored in the memory.

Comment: @MikeCAT Oh. Yes. Makes sense sir.

Comment: Our instructor asked us to create new instruction called "newi" and the thing it was doing was PC=200($s1)  (we are making program counter = 200+ adress of s1.) Thats why i asked. Do you have an idea about this question ?

Comment: Registers have names (5 bits) and hold values (32 bits), but unlike memory, registers don't have addresses.  You might have heard them say *the address in $s1*, which is another way of saying *the value (held) in $s1*, with the special meaning that this value in $s1 would be taken by humans as a pointer, aka a memory address.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thanks sir. I understand that registers dont have adress but only thing that i dont understand is:  When we are doing "J 200($s1)" instruction, why are we considering s1's 32 bit value, and not s1's memory value. This is my main question.

Comment: @ErikEidt i mean while designing "J 200($s1)" in datapath, we are considering "($s1)" as s1's register value. Not s1's memory adress. Why? A friend of mine told me that its about indirect-direct adressing but i couldnt understand what he meant.

Comment: Does your made-up `J 200($s1)` set PC = `200 + $s1`, or does does it load a new PC value from memory at that address (i.e. a memory-indirect jump)?

Comment: @PeterCordes Based on dear Erik's answer, i asked my instructor and its PC=200+$s1. The main problem was it. I didnt know what my instructor implied. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must start with `$s1`'s contents -- the value held there.  From the 32-bit value held by that register, we can do:

1. $s1 + 200 (simple addition), or,
2. Mem[$s1 + 200] ([displacement addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Base_plus_offset,_and_variations)), or
3. Mem[$s1] + 200 (there's some name for this but it is not a common addressing mode).

In your case, as you want to do PC = 200($s1), my guess would be (1) or (2).

Because assignment to the PC (PC=...) already implies another memory fetch *that will occur for the very next instruction — to fetch the machine code instruction to execute —* we need to question whether a memory fetch (in the new `J` instruction) is desired or not.  The syntax `J 200($s1)` is ambiguous here (b/c of the implied indirection of the execution cycle: IR=Mem[PC] that naturally occurs during instruction execution), so, you'll have to ask whether the 200($s1) is the simple address of machine code to fetch and execute next (very likely), or, the address of a data pointer that tells where the machine code is.

The former, (1), would be reasonable as the next operation the processor performs is IR = Mem[PC], so across two instructions (this `J` and the next instruction), that says execute the instruction at Mem[PC] (where PC=$s1+200) so equivalent to saying to execute the instruction at Mem[$s1+200]: a single level of indirection, which says to use the location, $s1+200, to assign to the PC=$s1+200, and use subsequently as a the location of program/machine code instructions.

*IR is the instruction register, used internally to describe the processor's fetch of the machine code instruction and holding of it for decode and further execution.*

The latter, (2), would also be reasonable, and it says execute the instruction at Mem[Mem[$s1+200]], an extra level of indirection, appropriate if the intent is to use the memory location, $s1+200, as a data word, as a pointer to the next PC/machine code instruction, to be assigned to the PC so that the next instruction is sourced from that data pointer value.

Comment: I wish i had enough reputations to give you feedback sir. Thank you so so much! :)